# Is 1 Sv of alpha Radiation just as or more harmful for living beings than 1 Sv of Proton radiation?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation

Is 1 Sv of alpha radiation just as or more harmful for living beings than 1 Sv of proton radiation?

Comment: Well, for MeV particles, the alpha won’t get through your dead skin outer layer, while the protons will.

Comment: @FalconHeavy321 If you're asking about the effects of radiation on living organisms try asking on the [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/). There is some physics in your question i.e. how energetic particles interact with matter, but when it comes to the medical effects of the interaction that seems more like biology than physIcs.

Answer (score 2):

The biological effect is the same, since the effect of radiation type is already baked into the calculation.

The Sievert (Sv) is a unit of effective dose that takes into account the type of radiation and type of tissue being exposed.

Any text on radiation protection will cover what goes into calculating effective dose.